# Storing applicative version info in SPSS sav file

Tags: spss

I'm using C SPSS I/O library to write and read sav files.
I need to store my own version number in sav file. The requirements are:

1) That version should not be visible to user when he/she uses regular SPSS programs.

2) Obviously, regular SPSS programs and the I/O module should not overwrite the number.

Please, advice about that place or function.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a header field in the sav file that identifies the creator.  However, that would be overwritten if the file is resaved.  It would be visible with commands such as sysfile info.

Another approach would be to create a custom file attribute using a name that is unlikely to be used by anyone else.  It would also be visible in a few system status commands such as DISPLAY DICT and I think, CODEBOOK.  It could be overwritten, with the DATASET ATTRIBUTE command but would not be changed just by resaving the file.